Cascade select options is stripped on small screens

The cascade select options is stripped/not visible on mobile devices. Is there a way we can change position of those on smaller screens ?
The options should be visible on smaller screens as well without some part of those being hidden

Please open an issue at the repository of the Prime library you are using.
